# WMS service not adding to the map in Silverlight

Tags: arcgis, wms

I have created a MapService on ArcGIS Server 10 and enabled the WMS capability 
and wrote a code to add this WMS service on my Silverlight 4 map application but it does not add the service, the map is not visible, but when I add the WMS url in ArcMAP I can view the map
Please comment what am I missing here?
Code goes here

```
ESRI.ArcGIS.Client.Toolkit.DataSources.WmsLayer newLayer = 
    new ESRI.ArcGIS.Client.Toolkit.DataSources.WmsLayer();
newLayer.Url = "http://server1.com/arcgis/services/merged_soi1/MapServer/WMSServer";
newLayer.ID = "newLayer1";
newLayer.SkipGetCapabilities = true;
MyMap.Layers.Add(newLayer);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try specifying the map layer.  WMS allows for multiple layers so even if you only have one you may need to specify the name.  For example, the state of NJ offers a WMS here:

http://njwebmap.state.nj.us/njimagery

Put the URL in ArcCatalog and you will see a dozen or layers or so.  But if you try to add it to SL with your code, SL will not know which layer to use.  So you have to put something like this:

http://njwebmap.state.nj.us/njimagery?layers=Natural2010

Which gets you the 2010 Orthos.

Good luck.

Ernie